# Memory leak using glXCreateContext

Tags: opengl, xlib, glx

I have created a class to initialize and clear Xlib and glx properly.

```
OpenGLContext::OpenGLContext()
    :m_display(nullptr)
    ,m_context(nullptr)
    ,m_vi(nullptr)
{
    memset(&m_cmap, 0, sizeof(Colormap));
    memset(&m_swa, 0, sizeof(XSetWindowAttributes));
    memset(&m_win, 0, sizeof(Window));
    m_display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
    assert(m_display);

    static int dblBuf[] =  {GLX_RGBA, GLX_RED_SIZE, 1, GLX_GREEN_SIZE, 1, GLX_BLUE_SIZE, 1, GLX_DEPTH_SIZE, 12, GLX_DOUBLEBUFFER, None};
    m_vi = glXChooseVisual(m_display, DefaultScreen(m_display), dblBuf);
    m_context = glXCreateContext(m_display, m_vi, None, True);
    m_cmap = XCreateColormap(m_display, RootWindow(m_display, m_vi->screen), m_vi->visual, AllocNone);
    m_swa.colormap = m_cmap;
    m_win = XCreateWindow(
                m_display,
                RootWindow(  m_display, m_vi->screen  ),
                0, 0, /* width */ 640, /* height */ 480, 0, m_vi->depth, InputOutput, m_vi->visual,
                CWBorderPixel | CWColormap | CWEventMask, &m_swa
            );

    char* dummy[] = { "", 0 };
    XSetStandardProperties(m_display, m_win, "glxsimple", "glxsimple", None, dummy, 0, NULL);
    glXMakeCurrent(m_display, m_win, m_context);
    XMapWindow(GetDisplay(), GetWindow());
}

OpenGLContext::~OpenGLContext()
{
    XUnmapWindow(m_display, m_win);
    glXMakeCurrent(m_display, None, NULL);
    XFreeColormap(m_display, m_cmap);
    XDestroyWindow(m_display, m_win);
    glXDestroyContext(m_display, m_context);
    XFree(m_vi);
    XCloseDisplay(m_display);
}
```

Unfortunately, valgrind reports a memory leak.

```
==28742== 12,796 (584 direct, 12,212 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 631 of 637
==28742==    at 0x4C29F5D: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:263)
==28742==    by 0xBCD7E7C: driConcatConfigs (in /usr/lib64/mesa/swrastg_dri.so)
==28742==    by 0xBCDBDFF: dri_init_screen_helper (in /usr/lib64/mesa/swrastg_dri.so)
==28742==    by 0xBCDAF0D: drisw_init_screen (in /usr/lib64/mesa/swrastg_dri.so)
==28742==    by 0xBCD8583: driCreateNewScreen (in /usr/lib64/mesa/swrastg_dri.so)
==28742==    by 0x5295604: driswCreateScreen (in /usr/lib64/opengl/xorg-x11/lib/libGL.so.1.2)
==28742==    by 0x527412B: __glXInitialize (in /usr/lib64/opengl/xorg-x11/lib/libGL.so.1.2)
==28742==    by 0x5270154: glXGetFBConfigs (in /usr/lib64/opengl/xorg-x11/lib/libGL.so.1.2)
==28742==    by 0x5270B57: glXChooseFBConfig (in /usr/lib64/opengl/xorg-x11/lib/libGL.so.1.2)
==28742==    by 0x4E9A7CE: ??? (in /usr/lib64/librrfaker.so)
==28742==    by 0x4E5B676: glXChooseVisual (in /usr/lib64/librrfaker.so)
==28742==    by 0x46D23B: Zion::Core::OpenGLContext::OpenGLContext() (OpenGLContext.cpp:23)
```

Note that I’m using VirtualGL (which explains librrfaker.so). Is there something I did wrong? or should I assume this is a bug on VirtualGL’s side?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't automatically assume that's it a bug. valgrind will sometimes return false positive results when dealing with optimised libraries. To be certain you need to ensure you are running against an unoptimised build of the library.

**Edit**

[This extract from a valgrind manual](http://www.network-theory.co.uk/docs/valgrind/valgrind_11.html) suggest that this is only an issue when it checks for uninitialised variables. I remember being hit by false positives before but when I think of it now it was indeed for uninitialised values.

Comment: Okay. Why are there false positives?

Comment: I don't know the detailed reason but I assume it's similar to the way a debugger is not very reliable when stepping through optimised binaries.

Comment: No offense, but it sounds unlikely to me. If I remember correctly what I read from Valgrind’s documentation, valgrind emulates a processor and has the program run on it. From this extended processor it deduces which memory location were affected by the opcodes. That’s why I can’t see how optimized code could make a difference at such level.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely a real memory leak, Valgrind detects leaks in libraries too.

In practice - if these are functions only every called once on initialization for example. While they are technically leaks - you can safely ignore them, or if you like you could investigate the leak up-stream, if the source is available.

---

Checking the docs, on [glXChooseFBConfig](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glXChooseFBConfig.xml) the return value is expected to be freed with `XFree` called on it.